# In CodeIgniter 2.x Encryption Method, where is the IV stored?

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

I noticed that we should store `IV (Initialization Vector)` when `Encrypting in CBC mode` (for example storing IV as a plain text in database next to the encrypted string)

But CodeIgniter's Encryption Class does not return any IV and it is not stored in database or anywhere else either, it simply takes a 32 character $key and $string and provides encrypted text:

```
$msg = 'My message to encrypt';
$key = 'super-secret-key';

$encrypted_string = $this->encrypt->encode($msg, $key);
```

### My question is

What happens to the IV when using CodeIgniter's Encryption?

i'm asking because if it is dependent on the server or script or hidden somewhere, we cannot use the encrypted message anywhere else without the IV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked into the [code](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/v2.1.0/system/libraries/Encrypt.php#L321) and at least for version 2.1.0, the IV is simply prepended to the ciphertext. Since the IV is not supposed to be secret, but only random (to ensure semantic security), it can be sent in the clear.

CodeIgniter also implements the unusual `_add_cipher_noise()` function on the IV + ciphertext which changes both completely. It is a simple additional encryption method to hide the IV and prevent man-in-the-middle attacks on the first block of the ciphertext.

The usual solution for this is to authenticate the IV + ciphertext. CodeIgniter 3 seems to provide a [function](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.0.0/system/libraries/Encryption.php#L347-L377) to add an authentication tag to the ciphertext derived through HKDF.

Comment: I was thinking it might be inside the encrypted string but i wasn't sure it is possible/secure, Thank you for explanation.

Comment: Please note that CodeIgniter also applies `_add_cipher_noise()` function on the IV + ciphertext which changes both completely. It also makes it slightly less portable across different AES-CBC implementations.

Comment: The old `Encrypt` class is not secure. Please upgrade to CI3 and use `Encryption` instead.